# How to phrase multiple descriptions each applied to multiple objects

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

Let's say I've got two departments: Sales and Marketing.  Each department generates Reports and Recommendations.

To refer to all of that, I've written: "Sales and Marketing Reports and Recommendations".  However, that sounds kind of ambiguous to me.   Is there a better way to phrase this that makes it more clear while not becoming too unwieldy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the word "department" and you'll have an unambiguous description:

***"Sales and Marketing Departments' Reports and Recommendations"***

> Note the **s'** because you are referring to the Reports and
>   Recommendations of multiple departments.